# SVG <use> element performance

Tags: svg

Imagine you have an SVG image with approximately 7500 circles that can have one of four predetermined radii. Is it better to use 7500 `<use>` elements linked to four different `<circle>` elements, each `<use>` with different `x`, `y`, and `class` attributes, or is it better to use 7500 `circle` elements, all with different `cx`, `cy`, `r`, and `class` attributes? Which will offer the best performance with rendering, scrolling, and possibly some transforms?

Comment: This is an easy performance test for you to do yourself. What have you tried so far?

Comment: That's a lot of circles. Here's a page that let's you experiment with different numbers of small circles being animated. http://tommykrueger.com/projects/d3tests/performance-test.php

Comment: @Phrogz how would i go about testing something like this??